# Order and de-dup data in attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Each `<leg>` records the leg of a trip. The trip is recorded in document order. Some legs start and end in the same place (e.g., from MA to MA), some go place to place (e.g., from MA to CT). Some data about start and end locations is missing.

```
<trip>
  <leg start="MA" stop="MA" />
  <leg start="MA" stop="CT" /> 
  <leg start="NY"           />
  <leg                      />
  <leg start="DE"           />
  <leg            stop="DE" />
  <leg start="NY" stop="PA" />
</trip>
```

Using XSLT/XPATH 1.0, I want a list of the places, in the order visited:

```
<trip>
  <place>MA</place>
  <place>CT</place>
  <place>NY</place>
  <place>DE</place>
  <place>NY</place>
  <place>PA</place>
</trip>
```

**Edit:**

OK, I think I see how to do it:

```
<xsl:template match="leg" mode="tour">
    <xsl:if test="string(@start)">
        <place><xsl:value-of select="@start"></place>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string(@end)">
        <place><xsl:value-of select="@end"></place>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:variable name="rtfPlaces">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="trip/leg" mode="tour" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="places" select="exslt:node-set($rtfPlaces)" />

<xsl:variable name="uniquePlaces" select="$places/place[1] | $places/place[.!=preceding-sibling::place[1]]" />
```

Solution: Do indeed handle it in two passes. Get @start and @end in the needed order by writing them out separately. Then select unique values on a second pass.

That doesn't get me the `trip` element in the output, but I don't think I really need that.

And it does require the node-set extension, but that is OK too.

If it can all be done in one pass, I don't see how.

Comment: How nice... Is there a question you'd like to ask? This is not a "write this code for me" site, it's "here's what I've tried, what's wrong with it?"

Comment: I've generally had more friendly replies when I didn't take people through my personal bunglings than when I do. My apologies for the offense. On this one, I'm not sure where to start. I thought I'd serialize and then de-dup, but since attributes are not processed in document order, how do I interleave the starts and stops in order? While head-scratching on that, I got less comfortable that even serializing first was the right strategy. I'll keep wandering, check back in case someone offers help to a lost soul, and edit the post once I have a coded failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get it in one pass...

**XML Input**

```
<trip>
  <leg start="MA" stop="MA" />
  <leg start="MA" stop="CT" />
  <leg start="NY"           />
  <leg                      />
  <leg start="DE"           />
  <leg            stop="DE" />
  <leg start="NY" stop="PA" />
</trip>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="trip">
    <trip>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </trip>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--This is so we don't get duplicate entries 
    for both attributes when they are the same.-->
  <xsl:template match="@stop[.=parent::*/@start]"/>

  <xsl:template match="@start|@stop">
    <xsl:if test="not(parent::leg/preceding-sibling::leg[1][@start = current() or @end = current()])">
      <place><xsl:value-of select="."/></place>      
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<trip>
   <place>MA</place>
   <place>CT</place>
   <place>NY</place>
   <place>DE</place>
   <place>NY</place>
   <place>PA</place>
</trip>
```

You could also add this template to be 100% sure that `@start` was getting processed before `@stop`:

```
  <xsl:template match="leg">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@start"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@stop"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Much better. Thanks! In my XSLT learning, I don't yet think to use the XSLT prioritizer as you did to cover start = stop. Good lesson for me. +1, Q answered. (If you have a mind to uptick the original Q, please do.)